# $_GET is empty - no htaccess active

Tags: php

For a URL - `test.php?qqq=123`

`$_GET` is empty.

I have deactivated the .htaccess files, so there should be no rewrites happening.
This occurs in the root folder and sub directories.

What might be causing the loss of $_GET data?

Comment: Just to be certain, does `var_dump($_GET);` and `var_dump($_GET['qqq'])`; show that it's empty?

Comment: If it's not .htaccess, then it may be something within your conf file(s) that is causing a URL rewrite.

Comment: it appears to be working now.I'd put this down to the .htaccess not being deleted after all. Thanks guys.